# How to allow multiple sessions in Ubuntu - xrdp?

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

I have an Ubuntu server.
I need the possibility to connect 2 users in the same time.
I use Microsoft Remote Desktop software to connect to Ubuntu server from my Mac.
But if I do the same connect from another Mac, the firs session is ended.
I tried different ways, changed file sesman.ini, xrdp.ini, but no success.
Max connections is set to 50 in XRDP file.

Are there any other possibilities?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please do not be trigger happy down voting questions. The question is very clear and completely understandable. The fact you don't understand the question is indicative you are unfamiliar with the issue or the solution. Do not blame the asker for your inadequacies.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're trying the same user from two different clients or if you're trying two different users. I've found two links that may answer your question: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=16698, but to tell you the truth, I never tried this using xrdp with multiple users, instead, I use ThinLinc, because it is very fast, easy to configure and has all the features that I needed so far. It is a server/client application and while the server runs on Linux, the client runs on windows/mac/linux and even directly from the web browser. ThinLinc is free for up to 5 simultaneously connected users.